# Eastern European Philosophy

Tags: history-of-philosophy, phenomenology

According to [this](http://www.thebestschools.org/features/most-influential-living-philosophers/) (at least when it comes to [citations and ratings](http://www.thebestschools.org/features/most-influential-living-philosophers/selection-methodology/)), the most influential philosophers are continental/analytical and are active in either US or Britain.

Are there any important Eastern and Central European philosophers working, teaching and writing today (except Zizek, of course)? Are there any openly available and updated resources on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, there are more philosophers working teaching writing and getting published today than ever. What we don't have is the cult of personality, the famous name arising from the vacuum of a small number of philosophers for decades or centuries at a time.

It's not limited to only living philosophers, but check out the "[Lists of philosophers by language, nationality, religion, or region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_philosophers)"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lithuanian_philosophers
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Romanian_philosophers
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_philosophers
and from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Slovene_philosophers

> Post-World War II philosophy
>   Phenomenologists
>   Ivo Urbančič (born 1930)
>   Tine Hribar (born 1941)
>   Dean Komel (born 1960)
>   Personalists
>   Edvard Kocbek (1904–1981)
>   Edvard Kovač (born 1950)
>   Marxists
>   Božidar Debenjak (born 1935)
>   Lev Kreft (born 1951)
>   Lacanians and critical theorists
>   <s>Slavoj Žižek (born 1949)</s>
>   Renata Salecl (born 1962)
>   Mladen Dolar (born 1951)
>   Rastko Močnik (born 1944)
>   Rado Riha (born 1948)
>   Jelica Šumič Riha (born 1958)
>   Alenka Zupančič (born 1966)